# No me funciona el evento mouseclicked para menu item

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos

No me funciona el evento `mouseclicked` para menu item en swing. Lo cambié a `mousepressed` y me funciona.. es prácticamente lo mismo, pero quería saber a qué se debe esto que no funcione en un menu item.

EDITADO : el codigo era generado automaticamente mediante interfaz gráfica. decidí simplemente irme por usar ActionPerformed para todos los eventos..

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, seria de ayuda que pusiera la parte de codigo, editando la pregunta que formulo, de manera que asi el resto de usuarios pueda ver el codigo que dice que no le funciona, y/o el que si le funciona, de esta manera es posible que encuentre ayuda mas rapido. Saludos

Comment: Java recomienda usar `Action` para "escuchar" los menu items y otros componentes. Mira aquí: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html Está en inglés, pero es recomendable conocer esta información. Verás también código de ejemplo, usando menues precisamente :)

Comment: Cuando preguntas sobre comportamientos de tu código, siempre das más oportunidad para mejores respuestas y soluciones más concretas si compartes tu código. Si tienes excepciónes, es recomendable de compartirlos por lo menos hasta donde se encuentra tu propio código y ayuda mucho de marcar las líneas a que se refiere la excepción en el código compartido.

Answer (score 1):

El `JMenuItem` es subclase de `AbstractButton`. Generalmente funciona bien de simplemente implementar `ActionListener` en tu `JFrame` y reaccionar a tu menu en `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.

```
public class MiClase extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    ...
    // necesitas un campo en tu clase para la referencia desde actionPerformed
    JMenuItem m1; 

    // en el constructor
    public Miclase(){
        m1 = new JMenuItem("menu 1");
        m1.addActionListener(this);
    ...
    }
    ...
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == m1) hazAlgo();
        ...
    }
```

Para controlar más fino el contexto de la acción, puedes usar `getModifiers()` y/o `getId()` del [`ActionEvent`(API en ingles)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html).

Comment: Aunque comparar la fuente del evento con un componente en concreto es algo extendido, cuando hablamos de menús y un listener compartido, veo más elegante comparar el `actionCommand` con un `switch` el listener puede reaccionar a varios botones o combinaciones que vayan a hacer lo mismo sin añadir los OR y es más descriptivo que el nombre de una variable que, por otra parte, no te hace falta que esté en el contexto que pueda llamar el `actionPerformed`. Podrías añadirlo a la respuesta.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n ya comenté al OP que puede recibir mejores respuestas si esta dispuesto de mostrar más de sus propios esfuerzos, y no quiero destruir mi propia enseñanza. Si el OP acepta mi (o otra) respuesta, me puedo dar la libertad de mejorar la pregunta para ser de mejor uso para la comunidad, por mientras respeto el derecho del OP de preguntar al nivel que quiere hasta que tiene su solución que le sirve. Si no hay hay otra respuesta que complementa la mía hasta esta altura, voy a considerar de ampliar pregunta y respuesta a una forma más canónica.